# Voting to close as duplicate on Area 51

Tags: feature-request, support, vote-to-close, area-51, site-proposal

Why can't you select which proposal on Area 51 would be a duplicate of the one you're voting to close?

I imagine in the future there could be a follower, questions, etc. migration between them. How it's implemented now it just closes the proposal "as duplicate" but without saying which one it's a duplicate of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[Closed as duplicate]` doesn't just cover duplicates Proposals, but also covers Proposals that duplicate other Stack Exchange *sites*.

The close reasons were deemed "good enough for now." They will likely need some work as the humans come up with their own brand of random craziness. I didn't want to spend too much time manufacturing reasons to close a Proposal when it is better to observe actual, native behavior in the wild.