# Advice for closing proposals on Area 51? How can I wield this power?

Tags: discussion, area-51, vote-to-close

What is an equivalent of [I just crossed the 3K threshold! Any tips for responsibly wielding this power?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56153/i-just-crossed-the-3k-threshold-any-tips-for-responsibly-wielding-this-power) for Area 51?

Comment: I think like everywhere else you should err on the side of leaving something open.  If it's not strictly against the FAQ (offensive, duplicate, etc) leave it to the Double D's  to close.

Comment: And BTW you are not 3k yet on '51, you're exactly `1,956` at this second.

Comment: @rlb  you only need 2k, see the faq :)

Comment: I'm flagging to close this question as off-topic because it's no longer possible for community members to vote to close Area 51 proposals; as of a few years ago, only moderators can close proposals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I close a proposal (particularly duplicates), sometimes I take a wait-and-see approach. There might be a **good reason** to have a duplicate proposal. Perhaps there is a unique aspect to the proposal that the author wishes to pursue. That doesn't mean I have to *agree* with him. Those cases are usually decided by the (lack of) support by the community.

Maybe the author is better suited to launching a successful campaign: If the author is some world-class maven in [subject] who wrote a *better* proposal, asks better questions, rallies more support, blogs about it enthusiastically, and it takes off. Proposals that *look* the same aren't necessarily equal. So I give it a bit of a chance to see where it goes.

But I stay on top of it and check back often. Sometimes a duplicate proposal was placed inadvertently (the search didn't bring up the duplicate). In those cases, the author is usually more than happy to support the *other* proposal. If nothing *special* happens with the proposal I'm watching, there's no use in splitting up the subject, so I close it.

I usually leave a comment indicating that the author may follow up with a *reason* they placed the apparently-errant proposal.

Answer (score 1):

It should be pretty obvious what kind of proposals need to be closed, like obvious duplicates or completely ridiculous joke proposals. The only grey area here is that what might seem to you like a spurious proposal might not actually be so, so I'd at least leave a comment on what might look like a dubious case to check and make 100% sure before throwing your weight around.

Comment: Now why do you have to drag Welbog into everything that you consider ridiculous? A lot of people backed at least one of his proposal, many thinking it would be condoned since it was allowed to live so long. It was addressed. Move along ... move along ...

Comment: OK I deleted that.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to **do your reading**. Since you have 3k obviously you've been eating your wheaties, but it's always best to keep in touch with what Meta's been talking about, especially in those touchy areas:

- [Voting to close as duplicate on Area 51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53699/voting-to-close-as-duplicate-on-area51)
- [Near-duplicate or "subset" proposals on Area 51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54697/near-duplicate-or-subset-proposals-on-area51)